# Why Unity Event work in wrong way ? Or is it me?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor

I try to get an MouseUp event in OnGUI Function in my MonoBehabiour script.

But it always returns "Layout" and "Repaint".

```
    private void OnGUI() {
    Event e = Event.current;
    Debug.Log (e.type);
}
```

My debug like a:
Layout
Repaint
Layout
Repaint
Layout
Repaint and so on

Why is it so ?
How can I know get event MouseUp ?

### Edit1:

```
Event e = Event.current;
    int s = e.button;
```

I can know when I click on mouse button 0, but how can I Know when I get MouseUp Event ?

### Edit2:

I want to work it in editor and not in play mode.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get event MouseUp event with `if (Event.current.type == EventType.MouseUp)`.

Here is a complete code sample:

```
 void OnGUI()
 {
     Event mEvent = Event.current;

     if (mEvent != null && mEvent.isMouse)
     {
         //Get Mouse Down
         if (mEvent.type == EventType.MouseDown)
         {

         }

         //Get Mouse Up
         if (mEvent.type == EventType.MouseUp)
         {

         }

         //Get Mouse Move
         if (mEvent.type == EventType.MouseMove)
         {

         }
     }
 }
```

Now, to detect which mouse button:

```
 //Left Mouse button
 if (mEvent.button == 0)
 {

 }

 //Right  Mouse button
 if (mEvent.button == 1)
 {

 }

 //Middle  Mouse button
 if (mEvent.button == 2)
 {

 }
```

You can put those inside your  `if (mEvent.type == EventType.MouseDown)` and `if (mEvent.type == EventType.MouseUp)` code.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answer. But id does not work. I must say, that actions that I do I do en Editor and not in play mode. Does it make any difference ?